# I don't know how to change an input into integer with decimals

Tags: python, decimal

I've made a program that calculates the flat rate interest of a loan based on the amount borrowed, the %/year (interest), and the length of time to pay it back... 
here's where my problem starts:
I let the user input the years to pay it back, BUT, if the length of time is under a year the user is forced to use a decimal like "0.5" for example and it reads as an error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.5'", am I forgetting to do something???

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't parse a decimal as an integer? Integers are integral by definition. And 0.5 isn't integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `float("0.5")`? that might be more suited to your problem.